# Detect qualifiers of templated operator()

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm looking for a trait to detect and to extract the full signature (to check for method qualifiers `volatile` and `const`) of a templated `operator()`.

Which means `std::bind` expressions (without the use of `std::is_bind_expression`) and lambdas with auto parameters.
The expected **return type and arguments are known**.

For example something like:

```
template<typename Fn, typename T>
struct is_templated_functor { ... };

auto fun = [](auto) mutable { };
using ty = decltype(&decltype(fun)::operator()<int>);
// ty = void(decltype(fun)::*)(int)
// lambda is mutable ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
is_templated_functor<void(int), decltype(fun)>::value == true;

auto fun2 = std::bind([](int) { });
using ty2 = decltype(&decltype(fun2)::operator()<int>);
// ty2 = void(decltype(fun2)::*)(int) const
is_templated_functor<void(int), decltype(fun2)>::value == true;
```

Comment: How about `struct S { void operator ()(int); template <typename T> void operator ()(T); };` and more complex case with several arguments ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Don't expose return types of `std::bind` in generic code, and don't pass generic arguments to `std::bind`, as `std::bind` does more than just binding with results of another `std::bind`.  Second, do you want to know if a given `operator()` can be called with a `volatile` or `const` object?  If not, what distinct practical need do you have for the `volatile` or `const`ness of the actual template `operator()` in question?  In general, C++ does not allow you to learn *how* something was defined, but will let you know *how* you can use it, through existing introspection.  Doing so with `std` is ik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to @Yakk's comment i realized that i don't need to get the full signature of the expression to check if the expression is callable with a `const` and/or `volatile` qualifier, since the return type and arguments are known already.

Its possible to use a detection idiome to check if the object with a templated `operator()` is callable with the given quaifiers:

```
template<typename Fn>
struct impl_is_callable_with_qualifiers;

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct impl_is_callable_with_qualifiers<ReturnType(Args...)>
{
    template<typename T>
    static auto test(int)
        -> typename std::is_convertible<
            decltype(std::declval<T&>()(std::declval<Args>()...)),
            ReturnType
           >;

    template<typename T>
    static auto test(...)
        -> std::false_type;
};

template<bool Condition, typename T>
using add_const_if_t = typename std::conditional<
    Condition,
    typename std::add_const<T>::type,
    T
>::type;

template<bool Condition, typename T>
using add_volatile_if_t = typename std::conditional<
    Condition,
    typename std::add_volatile<T>::type,
    T
>::type;

template<typename T, typename Fn, bool Constant, bool Volatile>
using is_callable_with_qualifiers = decltype(impl_is_callable_with_qualifiers<Fn>::template test<
    add_volatile_if_t<Volatile, add_const_if_t<Constant, typename std::decay<T>::type>>
>(0));
```

Usage example:

```
struct callable
{
    void huhu(int) const { }
};

auto fun = [](auto) mutable { };
static_assert(is_callable_with_qualifiers<decltype(fun), void(int), false, false>::value, "1 failed");
static_assert(!is_callable_with_qualifiers<decltype(fun), void(int), true, true>::value, "2 failed");

auto fun2 = std::bind(&callable::huhu, callable{}, std::placeholders::_1);

// std::bind isn't const correct anyway...
static_assert(is_callable_with_qualifiers<decltype(fun2), void(int), false, false>::value, "3 failed");
static_assert(is_callable_with_qualifiers<decltype(fun2), void(int), true, false>::value, "4 failed");
static_assert(!is_callable_with_qualifiers<decltype(fun2), void(int), true, true>::value, "5 failed");
```

[**Demo**](https://goo.gl/3jFTbx)

Comment: That isn't quite right, but close.  What if you want to know there is a `Foo::operator() const&&` or a `Foo::operator() const&` overload?  If you want to know if As you want to be able to talk about rvalue and lvalue qualified function types, your add const has to first strip the reference off, add const, then add the *same* reference back on, which makes it a bit annoying to write.  Also, your implementation of the detection idiom is very C++03.  ;)  `is_convertible` is probably better than `is_same`, as your `Args...` are already converted.

Comment: If i pass T& `std::decay<T>` will convert it to T, since the qualifier of the `operator()` method are not dependent on it's reference type it's ok to remove references i think.

Comment: *nod*, spotted the decay buried in there.  Still not *quite* right thing, as `operator()` can be overloaded on `&&` vs `&`.  Yours won't detect any `operator()() const&`, as you do the detection in an rvalue context I think.  Generally, you should only use `decay` if you want to store an instance of something like `auto x = expression` would (or store a pointer-to-something).  No storage here, so decay is very questionable.

Comment: Oo i didn't even know that it's possible to add the reference type as qualifier (except if i add the qualifier to an operator declared out of the class)... for my needs it's enough to check for an l-value compatible `operator()`.